# Is it OK to copy a person's likeness in a realistic portrait without their permission?

Tags: copyright, legal, portrait

Suppose I am designing a set of plates for the next D&D books (which I am not, unfortunately) and suppose I need to draw a monk with a slightly sneaky face. I have tried several concepts out of my imagination and they all leave me frustrated.

While sipping a cup of coffee and feeling uninspired I decide to watch funny videos from [insert random goofy videos site here] and there he is! One of the actors looks exactly like I would like my sneaky monk to look like, down to the cheesy moustache and the mousy eyes.

I decide to "draw inspiration" from his face and design my character. He ends up looking amazing, with only one problem: I did such a great job that the character looks exactly like the actor. The actor is not famous, so it is not that everybody will say "oh wow, he just drew Al Pacino" but still, if somebody would know this actor, they would recognize the resemblance.

Is it OK (and by OK I mean is it moral and/or legal) to use this design without the actor's permission?

Comment: Interesting question, this reminds me of the video game "The Last Of Us" where one of the main characters Ellie looks like the famous actress Ellen Page. I don't think there was any legal action besides Ellen's people asking to make some changes to dissociate the 2 (Not 100% certain on this) but no legal action was taken. **Definetly not sure on this** but I imagine you could sue for defamation if the other party really wanted to.

Comment: If it’s not a famous actor, would it not be feasible to simply contact him (or his agent) and ask for his permission? Some public features are happy to lend their faces as inspiration for drawings and paintings and such things, even when those things are not related to them at all. @Andrew I think you mean _he_ (the actor) could sue, not that cockypup could?

Comment: Also similar along the lines of @AndrewH's example: [Lindsay Lohan Sues 'Grand Theft Auto V' Makers For Using Her Likeness](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/07/02/lindsay-lohan-sues-grand-theft-auto_n_5551566.html). I don't know any outcome of the lawsuit, though

Comment: What country are you asking about? Here's a detailed article from Digital Media Law Project about "most states" (so presumably USA) which seems relevant - http://www.dmlp.org/legal-guide/using-name-or-likeness-another - seems like a likeness in a portrait is legally very simlilar to a likeness in a photo.

Comment: @user568458: Very interesting comment. You should consider adding it as an answer.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Yes, one could ask for his permission. But my question is "does one have to ask for permission to avoid being sued?". I know that nowadays people sue for anything, but that does not mean they always win the case.

Comment: @cockypup it's  literally all I know on the subject... and I have no idea if that site is legit or what regions they cover. If someone wants to take that link and run with it though they should feel free.

Comment: If you'd upload that image to a stock image site, they'd ask you for the permission of that person even if it's a reproduction (to my knowledge). They usually require the same thing as when hiring models for photos and reselling the pictures. I don't know if this applies in your case, the illustration might look like Pacino but it's not really him. Maybe you'll need to add a few pimples! I can only suggest you... to ask the law stack!

Comment: I've always been anxious about "accidentally" appropriating the likeness of someone without realizing it. When illustrating I try to mix references to create a unique likeness, however **if I can prove how I "constructed" someone's likeness without meaning to, surely I'm not breaking the law? **

Comment: Slightly different question, but I've posted this to the law stack http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/5281/if-i-can-prove-that-my-drawing-illustration-was-constructed-from-various-image-r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Morally* is really impossible to answer. Everyone is going to have a different opinion on this and context matters.

*Legally* the issue is about **appropriating one's likeness**. This isn't strictly against the law, but like most intellectual property issues, there's some caveats:

http://www.owe.com/resources/legalities/7-issues-regarding-use-someones-likeness/

The one caveat that is likely most related to this would be:

> (5) Invasion of privacy by commercial appropriation / rights of publicity
>
> These rights are violated when a person’s likeness is used on or in connection with products or merchandise (“goods”), or to sell or advertise goods or services.
> With respect to artwork, the courts have generally considered works of fine art to be expressions of the First Amendment rights of free speech, and thus immune from liability for violation of privacy or publicity rights. Only commercial reproductions of the artwork qualify as goods under this standard.

Still, no clear/easy answer here. Context will matter a lot.